# Changing Selenium node's hosts file?

Tags: python, selenium, jenkins, hosts-file

As of right now I have 3 different nodes all pointing to the same staging environment, but I wan't to run a few separate tests on a different environment. Is there any way that I could change a node's hosts file on the fly before and after each test? I'm currently using Jenkins. The whole point is to have everything automated, changing the hosts files manually is out of the question.